# «Металлокомпозитный» — слитно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, сложные-прилагательные

Произошел спор с коллегой-корректором. Она утверждает, что надо писать "металло-композитный" (через дефис), а я считаю, что "металлокомпозитный" (слитно).

Answer (score 3):

Прилагательное *металлокомпозитный* пишется слитно.

В орфографическом словаре:
[металло...](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE) — первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно.

Металлопромышленность — металлопромышленный; металлопрокат — металлопрокатный; металлокомпозит — металлокомпозитный.

[Баллон металлокомпозитный](https://official.academic.ru/1346/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — многослойный баллон, в котором внутренний слой выполнен в виде металлической герметизирующей оболочки (лейнера), а остальные слои — из композиционных материалов...

Слитно пишутся и другие подобные прилагательные: нанокомпозитный, керамокомпозитный, углекомпозитный.

Comment: Я бы сослался ещё на орфографический словарь: "**металло**... – первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно"

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Добавила (плюс примеры).